# SketchUp API: How to add a check box to a menu item

Tags: ruby, user-interface, checkbox, menu, sketchup

I don't see it anywhere in the Ruby API documentation but just in case I'm missing something...

I'm writing a plugin for SketchUp and I'm trying to add some options to the menu bar. One of my options would work best as a checkbox, but right now I have to have two separate buttons. Is there a way to create a checkbox menu item with the Ruby API?

Here's what I had to do instead:

```
foo = true
UI.menu("Plugins").add_item("Turn foo_option on") { @foo = true }
UI.menu("Plugins").add_item("Turn foo_option off") { @foo = false }
```

...and then I just use foo to change the options. Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SketchUp can have check marks in menu items. Both menu items and commands can have a validation proc. The documentation for `set_validation_proc` gives this example:

```
plugins_menu = UI.menu("Plugins")
item = plugins_menu.add_item("Test") { UI.messagebox "My Test Item"}
status = plugins_menu.set_validation_proc(item)  {
  if Sketchup.is_pro?
   MF_ENABLED
  else
   MF_GRAYED
  end
}
```

Although for checkmarks you would use the constants `MF_CHECKED` and `MF_UNCHECKED`

http://www.sketchup.com/intl/en/developer/docs/ourdoc/menu#set_validation_proc

http://www.sketchup.com/intl/en/developer/docs/ourdoc/command#set_validation_proc

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen a checkbox menu item created from an extensions before, but I'm a beginning user so that's maybe why.

An other approach would be to do it like this:

```
unless file_loaded?(__FILE__)
    plugin_menu = UI.menu("Plugin")
    option_menu = plugin_menu.add_submenu("NameOfOption")
    option_menu.add_item("OptionA"){ }
    option_menu.add_item("OptionB"){ }
    file_loaded(__FILE__)
end
```

The file_loaded?(_ *FILE* _) makes sure the menu only is created once, instead of every time you load your script. I hope this is helpfull. Maybe some experts now a way to create a checkbox menu.